# "python" regex at least 1 letter 1 number, at least 4

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I want to choose 'MME73KH/A' in the below.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{4,}$")
findalled = pattern.findall('[최대10%혜택] Apple 에어팟 3세대 2021년형 (MME73KH/A) : 애플 공식 브랜드스토어') 
print(findalled)
```

Answer (score 1):

More than one example could have helped to understand your requirements. From what I read, you want a pattern of at least 4 characters, with at least one letter, one digit, and possibly a slash "/" char (from your example, `MME73KH/A`). This should do the trick:

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile('[A-Za-z\d/]+[A-Za-z][\d][A-Za-z\d/]+|[A-Za-z\d/]+[\d][A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d/]+')
findalled = pattern.findall('[최대10%혜택] Apple 에어팟 3세대 2021년형 (MME73KH/A) : 애플 공식 브랜드스토어')
print(findalled)
# output: ['MME73KH/A']
```

Decomposition of the regex:

```py
pattern = re.compile(
    '[A-Za-z\d/]+'  # at least one letter or digit or "/"    +
    '[A-Za-z]'      # exactly one letter                     +
    '\d'            # exactly one digit                      +
    '[A-Za-z\d/]+'  # at least one letter or digit or "/"    >= 4 chars
    '|'             # OR
    '[A-Za-z\d/]+'  # at least one letter or digit or "/"    +
    '\d'            # exactly one digit                      +
    '[A-Za-z]'      # exactly one letter                     +
    '[A-Za-z\d/]+'  # at least one letter or digit or "/"    >= 4 chars
)
```

This will retrieve strings like `MME73KH/A`, but also `32REGK2` or `ABCD1234`, while ignoring shorter strings or strings with only letters or only digits.